# NHibernate lazy loading doesn't appear to be working for my domain?

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate

I'm new to NHibernate, but have managed to get it all running fine for my latest project. But now I've reached the inevitable performance problem where I need to get beyond the abstraction to fix it.

I've created a nunit test to isolate the method that takes a long time. But first a quick overview of my domain model is probably a good idea:

I have a 'PmqccForm' which is an object that has a 'Project' object, which contains Name, Number etc and it also has a 'Questions' object, which is a class that itself contains properties for various different 'Question' objects. There is a JobVelocityQuestion object which itself has an answer and some other properties, and a whole bunch of similar Question objects. 
This is what I'm talking about with my PmqccForm having a Questions object
[image]

This is the questions part of the model:
[image: Question DOmain Model]

The key point is that I want to be able to type
form.Questions.JobVelocityQuestion

as there is always exactly 1 JobVelocityQuestion for each PmqccForm, its the same for all the other questions. These are C# properties on the Questions object which is just a holding place for them.

Now, the method that is causing me issues is this:

```
        public IEnumerable<PmqccForm> GetPmqccFormsByUser(StaffMember staffMember)
    {
        ISession session = NHibernateSessionManager.Instance.GetSession();

        ICriteria criteria = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(PmqccForm));
        criteria.CreateAlias("Project", "Project");
        criteria.Add(Expression.Eq("Project.ProjectLeader", staffMember));
        criteria.Add(Expression.Eq("Project.IsArchived", false));
        return criteria.List<PmqccForm>();
    }
```

A look in my console from the Nunit test which just runs this method shows that there is nearly 2000 sql queries being processsed! 
http://rodhowarth.com/otherstorage/queries.txt is the console log.

The thing is, at this stage I just want the form object, the actual questions can be accessed on a need to know basis. I thought that NHibernate was meant to be able to do this?

Here is my mapping file:
http://rodhowarth.com/otherstorage/hibernatemapping.txt

Can anyone hint me as to what I'm missing? or a way to optimize what I'm doing in relation to NHibernate?

What if I made the questions a collection, and then made the properties loop through this collection and return the correct one. Would this be better optimization from nhibernates point of view?

Comment: Can you please update the post wiht how you  are calling the above method?

Answer (score 0):

Just try to add fetch="subselect" to the mapping file for Questions component and see if this solves the issue with multiple selects to that table - you should now see one 2nd select instead of hundreds separate queries, e.g.

```
<component name="Questions" insert="true" update="true" class="PmqccDomain.DomainObjects.Questions" fetch="subselect">
```

See for more info - [Improving performance](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#performance)

Comment: When I add a fetch attribute to to that component I get "XML validation error: The 'fetch' attribute is not declared." so I tried adding it to the one-to-one mappings beneath it, but it says subselect is not a valid value (join etc do work, but dont improve anything)

Comment: I missed that the <component> doesn't support any fetch settings, so you may want to try to replace it with some collection mapping instead, for exmaple <set> and specify subselect there, e.g.  <set name="Questions" inverse="true" lazy="false" fetch="subselect">
            <key column="PmqccFormId"/>
            <one-to-many class="PmqccDomain.DomainObjects.Question"/>...<one-to-one's
        </set>